# React Project - Request to ExpressJS Server returns 400 - Bad Request

Tags: node.js, sql-server, reactjs, express, tedious

Parameters are set and once button is pressed, a request [Node request package] or fetch request is made to be received by expressjs request. While link address is created, response returned is 400 Bad Request.

I've tried both a fetch request and a node package 'request' and

**Server JS**

```
    const express = require ('express');
    const path = require('path') //core node module
    const app = express();
    const cors = require('cors');
    const router = express.Router();

    // app.use(cors())
    const publicdirpath = path.join(__dirname, '../public')
    console.log(path.join(__dirname, '../public'))

    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.static(publicdirpath))

    app.post('/testcall', (req, res) => {
        if(!req.query.startdate && !req.body.enddate && 
    !req.body.projectnumber){
        return res.status(400).send({
            success: 'false',
            message: 'dates or project or both required'
        });
     }

     //call stored procedures
   });

    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
   });
```

**JS Class that calls express JS**

```
    handleDropdownClick = (event, selection) =>{
        const { name, innerText, value } = event.target;
        console.log( event.target  + " : " + innerText + " : " + 
    this.props.formData);
        const request = require('request');
        switch(selection){
            case 1:
                //call api or stored procedure 
                if(this.validation()){
                    //call api
                 request.get({url:"http://localhost:3000/testcall", qs:this.state.formData} , function (err, res, body) {
                        if(err){
                            console.error('error with request: error: ' + err + '. res: ' + res +  ' + body: ' + body);
                        }
                        console.log("Get response: " + res.statusCode + ". Body: " + body);

                    })

                    //Using Fetch
                    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(this.state.formData);
                    fetch('/testcall', {
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'credentials': 'include'
                        },
                        body: jsonData
                    })
                    .then( response => { 
                        return response.json();
                    })
                    .then( response => {
                        console.log(response);
                    })
                    .catch(function (e) {
                        console.log("fail: " + e);
                    })
                }
                break;
    //more code
```

**Package.json**

```
    {
      "name": "app-name",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "main": "index.js",
      "dependencies": {
      "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
      "cors": "^2.8.5",
      "express": "^4.17.1",
      "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
      "react": "^16.8.6",
      "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
      "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
      "request": "^2.88.0",
      "save": "^2.4.0",
      "semantic-ui-react": "^0.87.2",
      "table": "^5.4.1",
      "tedious": "^6.2.0",
      "webpack": "^4.29.6"
     },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "test": "react-scripts test",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject",
      "dev": "run-p server start"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
      "extends": "react-app"
    },`enter code here
    "browserslist": {
      "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
      ],
      "development": [
        "last 1 chrome version",
        "last 1 firefox version",
        "last 1 safari version"
      ]
    }, 
    "proxy":"http://localhost:3000"
  }
```

**Index.js**

```
    import React from 'react';  
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

    serviceWorker.unregister();
```

*File Path*

```
public
src
 -api
 -components
 -storedprocedures
 -tabs
 -app.js
 -config.js
 -index.js
 -server.js
package-lock.json
package.json
```

Expected results would be for the expressjs to accept the call and complete logic.

**Actual results are:**

POST http://localhost:3000/calculatecommission 400 (Bad Request) 
- **for the npm package request**

request.js:149 GET http://localhost:3000/calculatecommission?projectnumber=&startdate=2019-06-02&enddate=2019-06-28 400 (Bad Request)
- **for fetch request**

Answer (score 1):

You can use **axios** or use proxy at front-end

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Axios as well, it's a whole lot easier to use then fetch. You can find out more here

https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/

Answer (score 1):

Got the same result with axios unfortunately. I'm wondering if the issue is that the express is server file is set up wrong. Maybe it's not getting the request at all.

Answer (score 0):

> request.js:149 GET http://localhost:3000/calculatecommission?projectnumber=&startdate=2019-06-02&enddate=2019-06-28 400 (Bad Request) - for fetch request

Any time you get an error like this, don't forget, you are literally allowed to run this command yourself in the command-line interface.  That will give you the exact error that the install script is actually running into, i.e.:

> GET https://www.google.com/

In my case, the error was: `HTTPS not supported without installing LWP::Protocol::https.`

So:

- 1. I resolved all of the issues from the `GET` command.
- 2. Since the network it was trying to access was private, I used `sudo npm install --s`.